# Unable to install lubuntu 18.10 on a UEFI system : BusyBox initramfs error

Tags: ubuntu, installation, boot, initramfs

I am trying to install the latest version of Lubuntu . 
I copied the ISO to a USB stick using the normal `'dd'` command. 
`dd if=/pathto-iso of=/dev/usbstickmount`

While trying to install through this usb stick , i get the below error :

```
 BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1u1) built-in shell (ash)
 Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) Unable to find a medium connecting a live file system
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone facing the same issue, i have the issue with the way the booting-USB was created from ISO. I created it using Rufus on windows and selected the ISO-option (this works for lubuntu 14.x ) with lubuntu 18.x we have to use this option as `dd` on Rufus